# WQL query that results in an AND in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query-based collection in SCCM that will target all computers with four specific programs on them.  These four programs can also be installed on computers that have nothing to do with the application I'm trying to target, so the collection shouldn't include those.  Only PCs with ALL 4 of the programs installed should be included in the collection.

The naïve implementation below doesn't work, but here's the logic of what I want:

```
SELECT SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name
FROM SMS_R_System
    INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS
        ON SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
    INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64
        ON SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
WHERE SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName LIKE "ArcGIS Engine%" AND
      SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName LIKE "Java 8%" AND
      SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.DisplayName LIKE "Microsoft SQL Server%" AND
      SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.DisplayName = "SQL Server Management Studio"
```

How do you get a logical `AND` here?

Note that SCCM's interface requires WQL, not T-SQL for collection queries.  Therefore, the COUNT operator is not available (and I believe the HAVING clause works differently).

Comment: If you need to check multiple records you probably want exists.

Comment: Most of what you describe sounds more suited to a powershell or dos script; if the application stores its configuration in a SQL database it's really just details of the tables and sample data that we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way but this will be easy to debug for you. You can join to the same table multiple times, you just need to give it different aliases each time, each of these joins can be used to filter on a particular program:

```
SELECT S.Name
FROM SMS_R_System s
INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS p1
    On p1.ResourceID = S.ResourceId
INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS p2
    On p2.ResourceID = S.ResourceId
INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS p3
    On p3.ResourceID = S.ResourceId
INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS p4
    On p4.ResourceID = S.ResourceId
WHERE p1.DisplayName LIKE 'ArcGIS Engine%'
AND P2.DisplayName LIKE 'Java 8%'
AND p3.DisplayName LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server%'
AND p4.DisplayName = 'SQL Server Management Studio'
```

Comment: Why was this solution voted down? If it isn't working correctly, wouldn't it be better to leave a comment why it's not working correctly, instead of punishing the poster for offering unpaid advice?

Comment: This solution wound up being the correct one. I didn't realize when I asked the question that SCCM uses WQL, which doesn't support the COUNT operator as T-SQL does.  Also, SCCM keeps 32- and 64-bit programs in different tables, so this solution actually lends itself better to that scenario (even though it's more of a clever hack).

Answer (score 1):

You could use 4 EXISTS clauses to look up each individual program. That essentially the same solution as the one that Andrew posted.

Alternatively, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name
FROM SMS_R_System INNER JOIN SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS
    ON SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
WHERE SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName LIKE "ArcGIS Engine%" OR
      SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName LIKE "Java 8%" OR
      SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName LIKE "Microsoft SQL Server%" OR
      SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName = "SQL Server Management Studio"
GROUP BY SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName) = 4
```